# "Edit Permissions" link in ionic/cordova app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

In the settings of your phone you can edit permissions for the apps you have installed. (Location, Contacts, Photos, Microphone, Camera, Notifications, etc.) In many apps now they link to this screen from inside their app. (Ex. SnapChat) How can I do this in a cordova/ionic app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is a plugin for everything, it just isn't always easy to find. https://github.com/CookieCookson/cordova-plugin-settings